# Will it work if I use \PassOptionsToPackage twice to the same package?

Tags: package-options

Sometimes I need to `\PassOptionsToPackage` under certain conditions. Would it work if I `\PassOptionsToPackage` multiple times to the same package?

For example, when I write:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{option1,option2}{mypackage}
\PassOptionsToPackage{option3}{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}
```

what is it exactly passed to `mypackage`? `option1,option2,option3` or only `option3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will load all options. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mytestpackage.sty}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{Apricot}{Test Apricot}
\textcolor{AliceBlue}{Test AliceBlue}
\textcolor{AntiqueWhite1}{Test AntiqueWhite1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I've edited the question.